# Left Outer Join returning only one result

Tags: mysql, outer-join

I can not figure out why this query is not working.  It returns only 1 result, but should be returning 21 results.  There is always a product to fetch from the database, but not always a review to go with it.

```
SELECT p.product_id, p.product_name, p.product_pic, AVG(r.review_stars)
FROM products as p
LEFT OUTER JOIN reviews as r ON p.product_id = r.review_product
ORDER BY p.product_clicks DESC 
LIMIT 21
```

Comment: You should post up sample data and your table structure that showcases the result you are claiming is occurring, or better yet, create an sqlfiddle for the SO community to use as an example.

Comment: Yes the avg doesnt always have a valid result, but i thought thats what the point of an outer join was?

Comment: Did you add the limit 21 just for this post; otherwise you really should remove that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because in the absence of `GROUP BY` clause an aggregate function **always** return **the only** row.

Your query should look something like this

```sql
SELECT p.product_id, p.product_name, p.product_pic, AVG(r.review_stars) avg_stars
  FROM products as p LEFT OUTER JOIN reviews as r
    ON p.product_id = r.review_product
 GROUP BY p.product_id
 ORDER BY p.product_clicks DESC
 LIMIT 21
```

Comment: That was it!  Thank you very much.  Works flawlessly now.